# How to check if button from user control was clicked?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, button, user-controls, actionlistener

It seems like a straight forward thing, but I can't figure it out.

How can I check if a certain button was clicked from user control?

my user control is `uc_test` and button name is `btnTest` .

I assume its some sort of event handler added to `uc_test.btnTest` ?

I'm working in WinForms.

Comment: Attach `Click` event for `btnTest`

Comment: WinForms, Asp.Net, WPF?

Comment: @KlausByskovPedersen WinForms, sorry should have mentioned

Comment: When you say "a certain button" do you mean 1 specific button, or 1 of many buttons? So you're trying to identify which button was clicked, rather than just a specific button.

Comment: @sr28 one specific button, and I always know its name.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel tried uc_test.btnTest.Click(); but I get an error saying something along these lines "Click can be only used on a left hand side of += or -="

Comment: Do you currently have a 'Click' event assigned to btnTest?

Comment: @sr28 No, only declared and styled it so far, I guess this is what I'm trying to figure out, how to ad a 'Click' event, so I can than use something like btnText clicked ... do something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you've created a button but want to make it do something on click. I don't often use Winforms but from memory double-clicking on the control in the form should automatically create a btnTest_Click method. If not, just go to code and put in a method like:

```
protected void btnTest_Click(object sender, Eventargs e)
{
   //do something
}
```

Then set in the properties of the button the OnClick event to btnTest_Click.

Comment: Indeed double clicking on it works, one note it should be EventArgs, not Eventargs. Thanks!